# Best way to create new div based on a specified length of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Sorry if the question doesn't make sense, mainly because it's hard to explain what I'm trying to accomplish so I will try my best to make you understand.

I have an inventory system that when receiving items by scanning their serial numbers, my application lists the serial numbers that were scanned as they come in.  What I would like to accomplish ideally is that say after every 3 serial numbers that are scanned my application should create a new div and essentially start a new line of scanned serial numbers, if that makes sense.

Here is a picture of what I would like to accomplish.

[image]

Right now I just have it working where as a serial number is scanned in, it goes accross the screen and they just keep adding to the right of that serial number.

Here is a snippet of my RecieveItems.js

```js
RenderScannedItems(){
        var scannedItems = this.state.ScannedItems;
        var serials = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < scannedItems.length; i++){
            
            var serial = (
                    <div style={{margin: '2%'}}>
                        {scannedItems[i]} |
                    </div>
            )

            serials.push(serial);
        }

        return serials;
    }

   render(){
    return(
     <div className="ScannedSerials" id="ScannedSerials">
         {this.RenderScannedItems()}
     </div>
    );
   }
```

My initial thought was that I create an if statement that checked if the length of the scannedItems % 3 was equal to zero and then create a new div, but it didn't work they way that I thought it would.

If anyone has any ideas on how I could accomplish this, that would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another var "serial group". Make another counter j=1 outside of your loop. In the loop add serial to serial group, then if j is 3 push your div of serials onto serials and reset j to 1. All this said, you're better off using CSS to accomplish this formatting ... here's a css example:
Outside of loop:

```
const serialdivstyle = {
  display:'inline-block',
  width: '28%',
  margin: '2%',
  border-left: '1px solid black',
  text-align: 'center'
};
```

Inside of loop (note the bar character deletion):

```
var serial = (
<div style={serialdivstyle}>
{scannedItems[i]} 
</div>
)
```

Comment: how would you go about it using css?

Comment: On each serial div set display:inline-block and width 28%

Comment: On that div you could also set border-left:1px solid black and text-align:center

Comment: Ok I will give this a try.  Also could you edit your answer to how your code would look for your answer.  I kind of understand what you are saying but it's still a little fuzzy.

Comment: Done, actually I set a const for the styles so they're easier to read. You might have other styles affecting the serial divs, so salt and pepper to taste ...

Comment: Nice thing about CSS is responsive design: for example on a narrow screen maybe you only want 1 or 2 serials per row, on a wide screen maybe you want to display 5 serials row - CSS will make this easier than manipulating div elements in the DOM

Comment: This works like a charm.  Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overkill but I would go with implementing batching method. To make it nicely reusable and a bit cleaner.

Something like this.

```
interface Array<T> {
    chunk(size: number): Array<T>;
}

Array.prototype.chunk = function<T>(this: T[],size: number) {
        var temporary = [];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i+= size){
            temporary.push(this.slice(i,i+size));
        }
                
        return temporary;
                
}
```

And then just use as simple array.

```
  const listOfItems= ["aaaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaaa"].chunk(3);
```

Sorry just noticed it's Javascript not typescript the code would be:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function (size) {
    var temporary = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += size) {
        temporary.push(this.slice(i, i + size));
    }
    return temporary;
};
```

working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEEYwQTwDwAqAfKgN7CqWpIAWArmANYAUAziAF5QBcqYdAWwBGsAJS9M2fMQDcwAL7Bgk3ADoADjAD2EHTnVRVtBo1QBeVHAZIIILWEJFmEGiFa8CAbQC6AGnZcvPzCYmQUVBEAbggwqNAC6lrYADbmqD5yERHhWZZJqMzRsSBpAAwyqCV4ca6sqslQYADmLhUgANQWAVCi5Lm58YkpGnSsNM61qqzJICjMIL4d3aKimf2K-ZuoOVkwUBB0MGBxUAlJCMlrW1kKSkj2rBCoCAhpngBEL18I776on98fn8Ad9fv9AUDwYCwSCvjCIfDod45MB7mBWFoGvUtE1mC8jPQmMwAMwrJRKIA)

Answer (score 0):

My idea here is chunk the array of the elements and then generate template form it.

```
const chunk = (elements, groupSize) =>
  elements.reduce((acc, nextElement, index) => {
    const row = Math.floor(index / groupSize);

    if (acc[row] === undefined) {
      acc.push([nextElement]);
    } else {
      acc[row].push(nextElement);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

const buildLayout = elements => (
  <div className="table">
    {elements.map((row, rowIndex) => {
      return (
        <div className="row" key={rowIndex}>
          {row.map(column => (
            <div className="column" key={column}>
              {column}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);

const elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const chunks = chunk(elements, 3);
const layout = buildLayout(chunks);
```